# How to fix missing characters and log microseconds?

Tags: php, datetime

I have instances where my logs for a particular task are displaying 10:31:06.500 for example (measuring down to the millisecond), and other times when it is missing characters, 10:31:06.0 for example. What do I need to change so it always shows the 3 character milliseconds? In addition, I would like to go one step further and also display microseconds. Help appreciated.

```
// Log to file
public function logs($msg, $file)
{
    $date = date("d-m-y");
    $time = $this->udate('H:i:s.u');

    $f = fopen("logs/" . $date . "-" . $file . ".txt", 'a');

    fputs($f, trim($time) . ",{$msg}\n");

    fclose($f);
}

// Get millisecond timestamps
public function udate($format, $utimestamp = null)
{
    if (is_null($utimestamp))
        $utimestamp = microtime(true);
    $timestamp = floor($utimestamp);
    $milliseconds = round(($utimestamp - $timestamp) * 1000);
    return date(preg_replace('`(?<!\\\\)u`', $milliseconds, $format), $timestamp);
}
```

Comment: Why are you rounding is milliseconds are important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing the microseconds will depend on your PHP version and on how you want to format the time:

**PHP < 7.1:**

1. Format `12:12:12.012342` (seconds.microseconds)

```
public function udate()
{
    list($microSecondsPastNow, $nowTimeInSeconds) = explode(" ", microtime());

    $microSeconds = $microSecondsPastNow * 1000000;
    //$microSeconds is now an int, so we need to add leading zeroes to achieve 
    //the desired format. E.g. '000001' when we have 1 microsecond.
    $formattedMicroSeconds = str_pad($microseconds, 6, '0');
    $dateFormat = preg_replace('`(?<!\\\\)u`', $formattedMicroSeconds, 'H:i:s.u')

    return date($dateFormat, $nowTimeInSeconds);
}
```

2. Format `12:12:12.012.342` (seconds.milliseconds.microseconds)

```
public function udate()
{
    list($microSecondsPastNow, $nowTimeInSeconds) = explode(" ", microtime());

    $microSeconds = $microSecondsPastNow * 1000000;

    //$microSeconds is now an int, so we need to add leading zeroes to achieve 
    //the desired format. E.g. '000001' when we have 1 microsecond.
    $formattedMicroSeconds = str_pad($microseconds, 6, '0');
    $dateFormat = preg_replace('`(?<!\\\\)u`', $formattedMicroSeconds, 'H:i:s.u')

    list($milliPart, $microPart) = str_split($microSeconds, 3);

    return date($dateFormat, $nowTimeInSeconds) . ".$milliPart.$microPart";
}
```

**PHP >= 7.1:**

Since version 7.1, `new DateTime()` fills microseconds with actual value. Previous versions fill with '000000'. So, if you are up to date with your PHP version, most of the work is already done.

1. Format `12:12:12.012342` (seconds.microseconds)

```
public function udate()
{
    $now = new DateTime();
    return $now->format('H:i:s.u');
}
```

2. Format `12:12:12.012.342` (seconds.milliseconds.microseconds)

```
public function udate()
{
    $now = new DateTime();
    $microseconds = $now->format('u');
    list($milliPart, $microPart) = str_split($microseconds, 3);
    return $now->format('H:i:s') . ".$milliPart.$microPart";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work. Now do you, or anyone else know how I can also implement a microsecond read to this; I want to drill down in to fractions of a millisecond.

Comment: @Ian I changed the answer to provide some examples. I hope it helps